# Can PHP be accessible offline?

Tags: php, ios, ipad, local

My Employer would like me to take a web application written entirely in PHP to be accessible while offline. (it has to be accessible by an ipad without internet connection.)

I have tried the following things:

- http://solesignal.com/draftcode/
- http://blog.smartbear.com/codereviewer/15-code-editors-for-the-ipad-for-free-or-very-cheap/
- https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/offline-pages-save-complete/id364859644?mt=8

Before I'm going to spend **any** money i have to be 100% positive it works.

Does anyone know how i can achieve this?

Comment: why don't you try creating a Sqlite database in device and updates the info to it?
Whenever the user is online, he gets the data from server and updates that.
But whenever he is offline, the data can be fetched from the Sqlite DB in his ipad or iphone

Comment: I have no idea how to do this, I also don't know if it would be usefull in this project. The project contains an array, containing 300 items, wich will be loop through to generate a huge form. User fills in the data ( in this case my Employer does. ) and then it goes through another loop creating a file wich contains the user input.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/?s=sqlite&cof=FORID%3A10

Comment: Thanks for the help but I'm looking for a bit of an easier fix. If I have to follow those Tutorials I am probably faster rewriting the project in JavaScript(Which is **not** a thing I am looking foward to do). Anyone else? Please?

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by `offline`?

If you're looking to embed the server within your app, you're out of luck, it's not possible nor allowed. However if you want to run a local environment in your computer, take a look at [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/)

Comment: I know about MAMP, and WAMP and all those applications for PC. I just need something that gives me acces to use localhost on ipad without the ipad having wifi or 4g connection. So my Employer can use the web application on the go, with it just being on his ipad.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing more about Mike's question, He's trying to run a website/webapp made in PHP offline/stand-alone on iOS devices.

As PHP is a pre-processor, this is not possible without a seperate server doing the magic. Depending on what this application has to do, I suggest you try to re-make the webapp so it does not use PHP. A lot of the things done with PHP can also be done client-side with JavaScript.

If you require more sophisticated things, try looking into the [Meteor Framework](https://www.meteor.com/features). It supports PhoneGap exportation natively so the applications can run stand-alone on mobile devices as apps.

EDIT: If you can use an android device, you CAN run a PHP server on the same device as the pages are displayed because android is simply more open then iOS. If you're not willing to re-write the PHP code to JS, grab an android tab and use a PHP server package for android like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.esminis.server.php) or another one that does include a MySQL server like [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.kslabs.ksweb)